# How to check FTP connection?

Tags: c#, ftp, connection

Is there a simple, fast way to check that a FTP connection (includes host, port, username and password) is valid and working? I'm using C#. Thank you.

Comment: Be sure to accept an appropriate answer to this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try something like this:

```
FtpWebRequest requestDir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.google.com");
requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
try
{
     WebResponse response = requestDir.GetResponse();
     //set your flag
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: I have implemented something similar to your solution anishMarokey, however this seems to fail when it comes to secure ftp sites. Do you have any insight on how to test a connection for ftps? Thanks.

Comment: For this code to work you also need to set the request method (i.e. requestDir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails).

Comment: @ChrisMitchell .NET doesn't yet support SFTP, but there are libraries like [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) that have that functionality

Comment: @flowy Just add: requestDir.EnableSsl = true;

Answer (score 7):

this is the method I use, let me know if you know a better one.

/*Hola
Este es el metodo que utilizo si conoces uno mejor hasmelo saber
Ubirajara 100% Mexicano
isc.erthal@gmail.com
*/

```
private bool isValidConnection(string url, string user, string password)
{
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
        request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch(WebException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow uses English as it's primary language.

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful.

```
  public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(string host, string user, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false; // useful when only to check the connection.
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either [System.Net.FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest_members.aspx) or [System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp_members.aspx) to test your connection using your login credentials. If the FTP request fails for whatever reason the appropriate error message will be returned indicating what the problem was (authentication, unable to connect, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using
`System.Net.FtpWebRequest` and then just check the `GetResponseStream` method.

So something like

```
System.Net.FtpWebRequest myFTP = new System.Net.FtpWebRequest

//Add your credentials and ports

try
{
    myFTP.GetResponseStream();
   //set some flags
}
catch ex
{
  //handle it when it is not working
}
```

Comment: -1 because `FtpWebRequest`  does not contain `GetResponseStream` method and `FtpWebRequest` does not contain constructor without parameters (does not contain public constructor either).

Answer (score -2):

This is from the msdn site to diplay files from a server

```
public static bool DisplayFileFromServer(Uri serverUri)
{
// The serverUri parameter should start with the ftp:// scheme. 
if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
{
    return false;
}
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
WebClient request = new WebClient();

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
try 
{
    byte [] newFileData = request.DownloadData (serverUri.ToString());
    string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
    Console.WriteLine(fileString);
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
return true;
}
```