# Quick and Easy way to Test if an ftp adress user/pass works?

Tags: .net, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check FTP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234242/how-to-check-ftp-connection)

Using VS.NET App
What would be very simple way to test is a connection is made to a FTP address using provided username/password just to validate that a user inputted a good address.

I just use Network.UploadFile to send a file but if the address is wrong just throws 500 error and it annoying.

I want to avoid going into the FTP classes and all that- Just looking for a simple clever way to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks- i did not see then when i searched SO- and not even on suggested answers either.. erh

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple clever way would be to use some FTP class or Network.Upload file to test it, wouldn't it?

How about implementing some error handling for the exceptions that are thrown and providing feedback to the user if the address is incorrect?

Comment: i was hopping for something like network.site.exists() :)

Comment: And what do you think that method would do? I've spent 30 seconds Googling and found 4 or 5 variations on the same answer (2 of them on StackOverflow). I would be surprised if you had to write more than 10 lines of code to complete this task.

Comment: Magic, of course - what else?

Comment: Yer i know, but yer but i mean like `My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable` to the same of ftp version.. danke shiet. Uno line.. i know what Google is and SO..